# CSS to lock <div> in place regardless of browser window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have incorporated the use of [GRIDMvc](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) in my MVC5/EF Code-First Application.

```
<div class="assetList">

    @*Images in Columns: https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/discussions/440977*@
    @try
    {
        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => @<a href="/INV_Assets/Edit/@o.Id" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm noDecoration"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> @*Edit*@</a>).SetWidth(15);
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => @<a href="/INV_Assets/Delete/@o.Id" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm noDecoration"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> @*Delete*@</a>).SetWidth(15);
            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => @<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm noDecoration verifyBtn" onclick="verifyAsset(@o.Id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> @*View*@</a>).SetWidth(15);
            @*columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => @<a href="/INV_Assets/Details/@o.Id" class="btn btn-default btn-sm noDecoration"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> @*View*</a>).SetWidth(15);*@
            columns.Add(o => o.Status.status_description).Titled("Status").RenderValueAs(o => o.Status.status_description).Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.Location.location_dept).Titled("Dept").RenderValueAs(o => o.Location.location_dept).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.Location.location_room).Titled("Room").RenderValueAs(o => o.Location.location_room).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.owner).Titled("Owner").RenderValueAs(o => o.owner).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.Type.type_description).Titled("Type").RenderValueAs(o => o.Type.type_description).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description).Titled("Manufacturer").RenderValueAs(o => o.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.Model.model_description).Titled("Model").RenderValueAs(o => o.Model.model_description).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.Vendor.vendor_name).Titled("Vendor").RenderValueAs(o => o.Vendor.vendor_name).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.description).Titled("Desc").RenderValueAs(o => o.description).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.asset_tag_number).Titled("Asset Tag #").RenderValueAs(o => o.asset_tag_number).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.serial_number).Titled("Serial #").RenderValueAs(o => o.serial_number).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.ip_address).Titled("IP Addr").RenderValueAs(o => o.ip_address).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.mac_address).Titled("Mac Addr").RenderValueAs(o => o.mac_address).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.po_number).Titled("PO #").RenderValueAs(o => o.po_number).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.invoice_number).Titled("Inv. #").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.invoice_number)).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.cost).Titled("Cost").RenderValueAs(o => "$" + Convert.ToString(o.cost)).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.note).Titled("Note").RenderValueAs(o => o.note).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.acquired_date).Titled("Acq. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.acquired_date)).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.disposed_date).Titled("Disp. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.disposed_date)).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.verified_date).Titled("Ver. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.verified_date)).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.created_date).Titled("Crtd. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.created_date)).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.created_by).Titled("By").RenderValueAs(o => o.created_by).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.modified_date).Titled("Mod. Date").RenderValueAs(o => Convert.ToString(o.modified_date)).SetWidth(20);
            columns.Add(o => o.modified_by).Titled("By").RenderValueAs(o => o.modified_by).SetWidth(20);
        }).WithPaging(10).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        return;
    }
</div>
```

This allows me to display table records easily with the ability to Filter/Sort and Paginate. Since I am showing a good number of records in the grid, I added some `overscroll` CSS:

```
.assetList {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    min-width: 800px;
    display: block;
    height: 530px;
}

.assetList table, tr, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.assetList tr {
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

An issue I was having is that the `Pager` would display just below the grid, WITHIN the scrolling div. This meant that if a user scrolled to the right to view record data, they would have to scroll back to the left in order to access the `Pager`.

To combat this, I added the following .css to visually place the `Pager` outside of the scrolling `<div>`:

```
/* When GridMVC is longer than <div>, overflow with scroll */
.grid-table {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.grid-pager {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Visually speaking though, this is not a perfect solution...

This is the `Pager` below the grid when in full-screen on a 1920x1080 resolution:

[image: Full-Screen Nav Pager]

This is perfect, but when I go to Page 3 which has 9 records instead of 10:

[image: Full-Screen Nav Page 3 9/10 records]

Kind of off, but still usable. Then if the window is shrunken in size though (say 1218x787), the `Pager` is no longer able to be found/used:

[image: Shrunken]

I can scroll all the way down in the browser window, but not see the Pager.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? Or does someone more experienced know how to lock the `Pager` in place to where it will be just below my scrollable  no matter the height/size of the browser window?

---

**EDIT**:

This is the HTML that is rendered by `GRIDMvc` for my `Pager`:

```
</tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="grid-footer">
            <div class="grid-pager">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><a href="?grid-page=2">«</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?grid-page=1">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?grid-page=2">2</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><span>3</span></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you move the `.grid-pager` element out of the `.asset-list` (maybe programmatically) and assign `position: relative;` with an appropriate top margin ?

Comment: @collapsar, Perhaps... Would you have an example or idea of how to go about that? In my EDIT I added the exact HTML that is currently rendered for my Pager.